# AWS CDK setup appsync with dynamodb table permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, aws-cdk

I am using the new higher level GraphqlAPI class instead of the lower level constructs to create my Appsync api and connect it to a table.

```
this.api = new GraphqlApi(...);
```

The new GraphqlApi instance allows you to simply add datasources:

```
this.api.addDynamoDbDataSource('name', tableRef);
```

If you look at the example code at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-appsync-readme.html, I notice that they do not create a role to grant permission for Appsync to access the table:

```
const itemsTableRole = new Role(this, 'ItemsDynamoDBRole', {
      assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('appsync.amazonaws.com')
});
```

This snippet I got from this example: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/appsync-graphql-dynamodb/index.ts

In that example they still use the `CfnGraphQLApi` construct.
So there they are adding the role and the are adding a policy to the role for a table with permission to do specific actions. Which makes sense.

So my question is, when using the `GrahpQl` class, if I don't add a Role I can't execute my queries. And if I don't add permissions like:

```
this.appSyncRole.addToPolicy(new PolicyStatement({
        actions: ['dynamodb:*'],
        resources: [`${table.tableArn}/index/*`],
        effect: Effect.ALLOW
      }));
```

then I am getting an error like:

```
"message":"User: arn:aws:sts::[ACCOUNT]:assumed-role/[ROLENAME]/APPSYNC_ASSUME_ROLE is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb[REGION]:[ACCOUNT]:table/[TABLENAME]/index/byEmail
```

So is this example for GrahpqlQl not complete or am I missing something else?

Comment: Looks like GraphqlAPI supports 4 types of auth types - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-appsync.AuthorizationType.html. Your code for the `GraphqlApi` construct doesn't show what you're using - `this.api = new GraphqlApi(...);`. The example you linked to is using `AWS IAM`. Refer to these docs for more on permissions - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-appsync-readme.html#permissions. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-appsync-readme.html#permissions

Comment: @ultimoTG I don't think what form of AUTH I am using is relevant (for the record I use Cognito and IAM for unAuth routes). My query is for the role that allows Appsync to write or read from DynamoDB. If I do not add that role, I am not able to access the database. I ended up using `new DynamoDbDataSource()` which allows me to pass in the service role. But when you use `addDynamoDbDataSource` you can't provide this role. I find that a bit confusing because I think you need IAM role as I mentioned before.

Comment: if you are importing the table you need to use the workaround documented here.  Other than that, I just did the standard data source creation and it worked.  https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/14687