# Restrict AppSync permissions in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to build an AppSync API connected to a DynamoDB table in AWS using the CDK in Python. I want this to be a read only API with no create, delete, update. In my stack I add the AppSync API:

```
# AppSync API for data and data catalogue queries
    api = _appsync.GraphqlApi(self,
        'DataQueryAPI',
        name='dataqueryapi',
        log_config=_appsync.LogConfig(field_log_level=_appsync.FieldLogLevel.ALL),
        schema=_appsync.Schema.from_asset('graphql/schema.graphql')
    )
```

I then add the DynamoDB table as a data source as follows:

```
# Data Catalogue DynamoDB Table as AppSync Data Source
    data_catalogue_api_ds = api.add_dynamo_db_data_source(
        'DataCatalogueDS', 
        data_catalogue_dynamodb
        )
```

I later add some resolvers with mapping templates but even after just the above, if I run `cdk diff` I see that this will create permission changes that appear to grant full access to AppSync when interacting with the DynamoDB table.
[image]

I only want this to be a read only API and so the question is how can I restrict permissions so that the AppSync API can only read from the table?

What I have tried was to add a role that would explicitly grant query permissions in the hope that this would prevent the creation of the wider set of permissions but it didn't have that effect and I'm not really sure where I was going with it or if it was on the right track:

```
role = _iam.Role(self,
        "Role",
        assumed_by=_iam.ServicePrincipal("appsync.amazonaws.com")
        )

api.grant_query(role, "getData")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64039735/aws-cdk-setup-appsync-with-dynamodb-table-permissions) I have swapped `add_dynamo_db_data_source` for `DynamoDbDataSource` as it has a `read_only_access` parameter. So I am now using:

```
data_catalogue_api_ds = _appsync.DynamoDbDataSource(self,
        'DataCatalogueDS',
         table=data_catalogue_dynamodb,
         read_only_access=True,
         api=api
    )
```

Which seems to then just give me read permissions:
[image]